# What breakpoints should enable if I want to walk through a simple query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have built the MySQL server from source and am able to run mysqld in gdb while running a MySQL shell in another terminal window. When I connect to the MySQL server I can interrupt the server in gdb and see that an extra thread has been created that is monitoring the created connection. I then continue the server in gdb. If I send the server a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

how can I set a breakpoint in order to see the parsing, planning, and access methods required to run this query? 
As a follow-up, I see that the server and the InnoDB storage engine both have their own SQL parsers. Why are there two?

Comment: There may be a thousand non-trivial steps in even such a simple query.  Have you read about the "handler"?  That may explain the 2 parsers.

Comment: Part of the reason I asked this, was b/c whenever I ran a backtrace on any of the threads, it would almost always contain 3 frames that looked like: `0xmemAddress in ?? ()`. This made it much harder to find functions. Does this mean that code was built without debugging symbols? I also found that `backtrace sql/sql_parse.cc:mysql_parse` or a backtrace on the handler would enable a backtrace on some totally random function in a different file instead of `mysql_parse`. Is there some gdb feature that might cause this result?